# Impersonate Admin User and Run Powershell Script

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-3.0, impersonation

I am trying to run a script as a different user using the impersonation library. This is a C# winforms application. When I run this code it is not changing the password. In fact no powershell script I enter within this block will work. Here is the code:

```
 PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
                    Runspace runspace = 
 RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
                    runspace.Open();
                    ps.Runspace = runspace;

                    //Run the password reset script under my admin account

                    var credentials = new 
  UserCredentials("user@domain.com", "password");
                    Impersonation.RunAsUser(credentials, LogonType.Interactive, () =>
                  {
                      ps.AddScript(@"Resources\test.ps1").AddParameter("username", username);
                      ps.Invoke();
                  });
```

Any helpful leads will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you trying to escape ``\`` in a string literal `@""`?

Comment: Thanks, I Didn't even notice it. Has been updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to post an answer to this. Instead of running the script within C#, I used the active directory library within the remote server administration tools. You can download this here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45520

Comment: this might be a solution to your specific problem but its not a solution if powershell is required

Comment: It might help others who are on the same path and have loser requirements. Also, the question is three years old at this point. If you are experiencing this issue you might want to open a new one.